# Where I can obtain the "stylus.bat"" for the File watchers of IntelliJ IDEA faminly IDEs?

Tags: windows, intellij-idea, stylus

According the IntelliJ IDEA documentation, the Stylus files watcher setup is:

> 1. In the **Settings/Preferences** dialog  click **File Watchers** under **Tools**. The File Watchers page that opens shows the list of
>    already configured File Watchers.
> 2. Click the **Add** button or press **Alt+Insert** and choose the Stylus predefined template from the list.
> 3. In the **Program** field, specify the path to the executable file:
>
> - **stylus** for macOS and Unix.
> - **stylus.bat** for Windows.
>
> Type the path manually or click the Browse button and choose the file location in the dialog that opens.
>
> [IntelliJ IDEA
> documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/transpiling-stylus-to-css.html#ws_stylus_installation)

The question is where I can get the **stylus.bat**.
If I install the Stylus globally by **npm**, it will be installed to **[Drive]>Users>[UserName]>AppData>Roaming>npm>node_modules>stylus** for the Windows case:

[image]

But there is no **stylus.bat**. Inside **bin** directory, there is the file **stylus** without filename extension, but this one does not work.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `<drive>:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Roaming\npm\stylus.cmd` should do the thing

Comment: Oh, it is directly below **Romaing\npm**... Thank you for the answer!